# amp keyword in python showing syntax error

Tags: python, dbscan

I am following a tutorial and I am confused what this line is doing because it's not running and syntax error:

```
rs = rep_points.apply(lambda row: df[(df['lat']==row['lat']) &amp;&amp; (df['lon']==row['lon'])].iloc[0], axis=1)
```

Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax at &amp

Tutorial Link: https://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/clustering-to-reduce-spatial-data-set-size/

Can someone help me what can I do instead of this or how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is probably to replace `&amp;&amp;` with a single `&`.

There are two mistakes that happened here:

1. The blog software replaced `&&` with `&amp;&amp;`. Because in HTML, `&` is special, you need to write it as `&amp;` in your HTML source to get a literal & in the browser. It looks like the blog software made that translation once too many.
2. The author wrote `&&` (the operator for logical `and` in languages like C) while they meant either `and` or `&`. Given that we're using dataframes, my initial guess would be that the right answer is `&`.

Comment: wouldnt that turn & into `&amp;` and the second time it would become `&amp;amp;`? also the logical AND in python is literally a keyword `and`, the `&&` like in C or Java wont pass in Python.

Comment: Yes, that's why I think it was escaped once too many, rather than twice too many. If you read the comments, you'll see that others have noticed that `&&` is a syntax error, so that's why I think the author also made an error.

Comment: So if this is so, then this line actually doing nothing as I guess my rs will be exactly same as rep_points given all of my rep_points also exist in df, which they are.